# Select rows which repeat every month

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to resolve on simple task for first look.

I have `transactions` table.

```
|  name  |entity_id| amount |    date    |
|--------|---------|--------|------------|
| Github |    1    |  4.80  | 01/01/2014 |
| itunes |    2    |  2.80  | 22/01/2014 |
| Github |    1    |  4.80  | 01/02/2014 |
|  Foods |    3    |  24.80 | 01/02/2014 |
| amazon |    4    |  14.20 | 01/03/2014 |
| amazon |    4    |  14.20 | 01/04/2014 |
```

I have to select rows which repeat every month in same day with same the amount for `entity_id`.(Subscriptions). Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: *every month* is something ambiguous. Do you mean "that happened in the same day for two or more consecutive months"?

Comment: Also I need to select first appearing and last appearing dates

Comment: look at datediff function.  compare all dates with the same entity_id.  if the datediff is 30, 31 or 28(29) for the given months then grab the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `date` column is created as a [`date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) type,

- you could use a recursive [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to collect continuations
- after that, eliminate duplicate rows with [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)
- (and you *should* rename that column, because it's a reserved name in SQL)

---

```
with recursive recurring as (
    select name, entity_id, amount, date as first_date, date as last_date, 0 as lvl
    from transactions
  union all
    select r.name, r.entity_id, r.amount, r.first_date, t.date, r.lvl + 1
    from recurring r
    join transactions t
      on row(t.name, t.entity_id, t.amount, t.date - interval '1' month)
         = row(r.name, r.entity_id, r.amount, r.last_date)
)
select distinct on (name, entity_id, amount) *
from recurring
order by name, entity_id, amount, lvl desc
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ffbac/18)

Answer (score 0):

group it by day, for sample:

```
select entity_id, amount, max(date), min(date), count(*)
from transactions
group by entity_id, amount, date_part('day', date)
```